# HEAD is now at 92387b1ef... Fix java version++

Tags: raspbian-stretch, opencv, pi-3b+

I have raspberry pi 3, I want to install OpenCV for python.
while I was doing that according to the following steps...

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install build-essential git cmake pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev
sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
cd opencv
git checkout 3.1.0
cd ~
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
cd opencv_contrib
git checkout 3.1.0
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3 get-pip.py
pip3 install numpy
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
make 
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig`

at the line "git checkout 3.1.0" it gives me this error:

`pi@raspberrypi:~/opencv $ sudo git checkout 3.1.0
HEAD is now at 92387b1ef... Fix java version++`

I am not sure if it means to update my java version...
so what can I do? any help, please...
Many thanks.

Comment: Doesn't Raspbian have a version of opencv in the repository?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that's not an error message coming out of git. Given that you asked to checkout a **tag**, git is telling you that you checked out a given *revision* (not a branch) and though you didn't write it, it told you that you are working in *detached HEAD*, in other words, you are working without a branch... which is perfectly fine if all you want to do is checkout a given revision/tag (as in your case) and don't intend to do any changes on private branches of your own or push stuff into other repos. So it's perfectly fine, you can continue working on your flow of instructions.

PS And the messaje "fix java version"? That's the comment from the revision that you checked out. Try this: **git show --summary 3.1.0**

Comment: Exactly, that ***Fix java version++*** is the commit message to which your `HEAD` is located now

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the default raspbian repositories addressed in your `sources.list`:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Then install OpenCV for python:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
rpi ~$ sudo apt full-upgrade
rpi ~$ sudo apt install python-opencv
```